# Bootstrap slider does not load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have written this html and included all files from cdn but I still see the slider without the sticky  label so what I missed ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.4.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.4.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            Slider with single value and label:<br/><br/>
            <span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">
            Example slider label
          </span>
            <input id="ex18a" type="text" /><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>

    </form>

<script>
    $('#ex18a').slider({
        min  : 0,
        max  : 10,
        value: 5,
        labelledby: 'ex18-label-1'
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Full example](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/#example-18)

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @NathanielFlick no all files is loaded

Comment: You need the data attributes on your html for it to work, try the example first, then your own code.

Comment: Any suggestions please for alternative slider library ? ....thanks

Comment: Assets are Bootstrap v3.

Comment: I love this one, http://rangeslider.js.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was researching this issue further, and it turns out the `bootstrap-slider` project is not 100% compatible with Bootstrap 4 yet. The contributors to the project are working on it, and it looks like a good portion of it is done, but there needs to be testing and such before it will be released to the CDN. Take a look at the project's progress on GitHub [at this link](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/pull/856) and more information on the tooltip issues [here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/689). Odds are you will need to either use Bootstrap 3, or find another library that has already been proven to work with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm this is only working with Bootstrap v3 as of now, changing the linked stylesheets was enough to display the label above

```js
$('#ex18a').slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  value: 5,
  labelledby: 'ex18-label-1'
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.4.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.4.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      Slider with single value and label:<br/><br/>
      <span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden">
            Example slider label
          </span>
      <input id="ex18a"  type="text" /><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

  </form>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```